# Cycles single side floor problem

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadows

I have this strange shadow behave on render in Cycles. Simple one side floor is rendered correctly if Z location is > 3cm. There isn't any other geometry and no overlaping with walls.
[image: z=0]
[image: z=5cm]
I'm new in Blender and I newer saw something like this in other 3d software/ rendering system. Thank you for the explanation.

[image]

Comment: Could you post a part of this scene to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/? Floor and some simple object on it will do. Just to see the issue more clearly.

Comment: I cleaned scene - floor, walls, printer - It's visible along the edge of one triangle..
(http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3264/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it was looking like **Z-fighting** but it is not. I've checked twice normals, doubles, holes and everything else what comes to my mind, nothing was an issue but...

**Vertices are not on the same Z location** (I don't know which one) but after selecting all floor vertices - <kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>Z</kbd> > <kbd>0</kbd> (it will place all of them on *Z=0*) everything is ok.

[image]

*Little tips: this machine is hovering over the floor and use Filmic Blender for this ;)*

Comment: Thank you for this solution and for your time. Thing is if vertices is not on same Z - how is possible that Z dimension of object is 0? And anyway, if it's not on Z=0 there will be just some not flat triangle - so shading should be slightly different but not like this.. I mean is that bug of shading in Cycles (blender render is ok). Thank you for tips I'm going to play with Filmic ;)

Comment: @Destrosvet I really don't know why it's happening. Maybe there is slight difference as you are using small scene scale. Try and dissolve edges one by one and preview result. There is something fishy with them. In edit mode I've seen even glitches as because of Z-Fighting. Adding Solidify Modifier helps too. First of all, and this is something I'm always aiming for - keep topology quads only. More fun, less problems ;) Also if you think my answer helped you consider accepting it and/or upvoting ;)

Comment: Yeah correct quad topology is also my priority - but in 3dsmax where I have years of experience ;) In Blender I haven't this kind of workflow in my hand yet ;)